# Selecting different columns in mysql with different query for same function in python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a database with multiple similar entry called `Email1`, `Email2` ... I have created a function to store the data within these columns. However, the function upon call is only able to store/update a particular column and not the other. I have this code:

```
self.query = ("Update registration set Email1 = %s where Username =%s")
```

I am using this same code but within a function, so when the function is called it keeps updating the same column `Email1` and not the other columns. Is there any way to update the column name within the query so that the same function and same query can be called again and again without typing the query itself? Thanks!

Comment: Why not use a for loop?

Comment: I can probably do this using the if-else condition.. however that is likely to increase the length of the code. I just want to know if it is possible to update the query column name itself.

Comment: why not to set email1, email2 with 1 set method? Some thing like update table set email1 = ISNULL({email1}, email1), email2 = ISNULL({email2}, email2) where ... Than you can set one email with one method. If some email is null it doesn't changes

Comment: Actually, the user input for email2 Is taken only after the function for email1 is called and it's value is stored. So, single set query is not possible in this case.

Comment: Sorry for mysql nvl function name is "IFNULL" not ISNULL. Worked with mysql long ago.

Comment: thanks for the advice! I'll look into it!

Answer (score 0):

You could try some thing like this

```
def update_registration(email1, email2, username)
    query = "Update registration set Email1 = IFNULL(%s, Email1), Email2 = IFNULL(%s, Email2) where Username = %s"
    data = (email1, email2, username)
    ...
    cursor.execute(query, data)
    ...
```

Using this function step-by-step like

```
update_registration('aa@example.com', None, 'Test')
update_registration(None, 'bb@example.com', 'Test')
```

In result will gave user Test value: 
**email1 = aa@example.com** and **email2 = bb@example.com**